# Asymptotics / litte-o-notation

Tags: asymptotics

Why is the following true?

\begin{equation}
(1+o(1))n^{r+2}2^{-r}+n_{(r+1)}-n_{(r)}2^{r}(n-r)^{2}2^{-2r}=o(n^{r+2}),
\end{equation}

where $n_{(r)}=n(n-1) \cdots (n-r+1)$.

In my opinion, the result should be $o(n^{r+3})$.

Comment: guess the $n^{r+2}$ term cancels out?

Comment: Ah thank you @SK19 , yes $(1+o(1))n^{r+2}2^{-r}$ and $n_{(r)}(n-r)^{2}2^{-r}$ are asymptoticly the same. I don't know, why I did not see this, but problem solved now.

Comment: You can try to write down a detailed answer to your question. On one hand you would exercise explaining mathematical thoughts, on the other hand this question would not stay without an answer :-)

Comment: Good idea! We have: \begin{equation}
(1+o(1))n^{r+2}2^{-r}-n_{(r)}(n-r)^{2}2^{-r}+n_{(r+1)}.
\end{equation}
We can show, that $(1+o(1))n^{r+2}=n_{(r)}(n-r)^{2}$.
We know, that $n^{r+2}$ and $n_{(r)}(n-r)^{2}$ are asymptoticly the same, since $n_{(r)}(n-r)^{2} \leq n^{r+2}$. 
Therefore, there is a sequence $c_{n}$ such that $n^{r+2}c_{n}= n_{(r)}(n-r)^{2}$ for $n \to \infty$. 
If we write $1+o(1)$ instead of $c_{n}$ we see, that there is only $n_{(r+1)}$ left, which is $o(n^{r+2})$.

Comment: I meant answer in the sense of "Do you really want to answer your own question?" ;)